# CircuiTikZ —How to create Constant Phase Element (CPE) used in Electrochemistry

Tags: circuitikz, circuits

Good day, Can anyone help with how to create a new component in circuittikz. I am trying to create the CPE element W shown in the figure below instead of the standard capacitor element.

[image]

Thank you.